# JQuery/JS как получить id у дочерних элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, search, атрибуты

```
<div class="products">
  <div class="product" id="1"></div>
  <div class="product" id="2"></div>
</div>
```

как можно получить `id` и сохранить в массив всех объектов с классом `product` у родителя с классом `products`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var d = $(".products .product").toArray().map(el => el.id); 
console.log(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="products">
  <div class="product" id="1"></div>
  <div class="product" id="2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: кулсторибоб, человек не знает основ, ты ему предлагаешь однострочную конструкцию, которой при желании(а оно будет) он не сможет манипулировать, а следовательно будет создан еще один цикл... + хоть бы `>` добавил между классами. Еще и `var` при 103к попугаев писать новичку в лицо. Тупа медвежьи услуги iгоря

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [];
for(let prod of $('.products:first').children('.product')){
    arr.push(prod.id);
}
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="products">
    <div class="product" id="1"></div>
    <div class="product" id="2"></div>
</div>
```